# jquery colorbox to show automatically when page fires up

Tags: jquery, colorbox

How can I get my colorbox to show automatically if a querystring is present. 
So far I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //if this is coming from continental
    if (document.location.href.indexOf("redirect=cfs") != -1)
    {
        //create box
        var $notice = $("<div>hello World</div>").appendTo($("body"));
        console.log($notice.text());
        $notice.colorbox({ inline: true, width: "965px" });
    }
});
```

But this doesn't help, because it seems you somehow need to trigger colorbox to show something?

**EDIT:** 
I just realised that you can use `$.colorbox`, but how do I get my content into it?

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code did it for me:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //if this is coming from continental
    if (document.location.href.indexOf("redirect=cfs") != -1)
    {
        //create box
        var $notice = $("<div id='partnerMove'>test</div>").appendTo($("body"));
        console.log($notice.text());
        **$.colorbox({ href: '#partnerMove', inline: true, width: "600px" });**
    }
});
```

So you can create an HTML element on the fly then use `$.colorbox` referencing the new element using colorbox's **href** setting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use colorbox's html property:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    if (document.location.href.indexOf("redirect=cfs") != -1)
    {
        var $notice = $("<div>hello World</div>");
        $notice.colorbox({ html: $notice, width: "965px" });
    }
});
```